# Angular: form.$valid is false, but form.$invalid is also still false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

In writing my own custom validation for forms in Angular, I've noticed there are use cases where form.$valid will be false (because I'll set it that way if input is incorrect), but checking for form.$invalid will still yield true, which causes validation to pass and submit the form. What would be causing this behavior?

Example code:

```
if (!vm.incentive.donor) {
   form.$valid = false; //if this gets set...
} 

if (form.$invalid) {
    return false; //...this never gets hit, form.$invalid is false
}

return save(goToPayment); //and thus the form gets submitted
```

Comment: I've reworded the question and added an example.

Comment: you can't "set" `form.$valid`, or `form.$invalid`, they are functions that check the form status,  doing `form.$valid = false` just adds a property to `form` that *hides* the function, but it doesn't change the validity of the form.

Comment: I think what you really want is `$setValidity` on a particular property on the form.

Comment: Ah, thanks Claies. So in the function that sets validation, I'd do "form.$setValidity = false", and then still leave the check for form.$invalid?

Comment: `$setValidity` is used to "Change the validity state, and notify the form.".  you don't set the validity of the form, you have to set the validity of one of the elements on the form.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

They're opposites. If the value is valid, then `$valid` is `true` while `$invalid` is `false` and reverse if the value is invalid. It's the same case as `$dirty` and `$pristine` as well.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. In the app I'm working on, though, I have encountered instances where I set form.$valid = false, yet form.$invalid will still yield true and cause the form to submit. Any idea what would cause that? I've reworded the question and added an example.